# Am I calculating the Anderson-Darling statistic correctly for comparing PDFs?

Tags: r, distributions, goodness-of-fit, model-comparison

I want to compute the Anderson-Darling statistic to use as a goodness of fit test for some PDF distributions. I am using R. I want to compare some models to the observations, which are my baseline.

Example data used below is here (just a few KB):

- https://www.dropbox.com/s/q1qulsbp2tjofqp/mod.Rdata?dl=0
- https://www.dropbox.com/s/7hqhrd5ijkjbhzv/obs.Rdata?dl=0

I have binned PDFs for each dataset (here an example named `mod`) in this `dataframe` form:

```
load("mod.Rdata")
load("obs.Rdata")

> head(mod)
       x        PDF
7993 1.5 0.19032062
7994 2.5 0.12746517
7995 3.5 0.09715163
7996 4.5 0.07751908
7997 5.5 0.06397796
7998 6.5 0.05358841

> tail(mod)
         x          PDF
8299 307.5 9.737257e-08
8300 308.5 9.737257e-08
8304 312.5 9.737257e-08
8308 316.5 9.737257e-08
8314 322.5 9.737257e-08
8315 323.5 9.737257e-08
```

Of course observations have the same form:

```
> head(obs)
    x        PDF
1 1.5 0.16176188
2 2.5 0.11178467
3 3.5 0.08787392
4 4.5 0.07250553
5 5.5 0.06132435
6 6.5 0.05254749
> tail(obs)
        x          PDF
308 308.5 1.239406e-07
310 310.5 1.239406e-07
312 312.5 2.478813e-07
319 319.5 1.239406e-07
328 328.5 1.239406e-07
329 329.5 1.239406e-07
```

You can easily visualize the data:

```
# Visualize data
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data=mod, aes(x=x, y=log10(PDF)), color="red") +
  geom_point(data=obs, aes(x=x, y=log10(PDF)), color="green")
```

[image]

I want to compare the two. What is the right approach? Here's what I did:

```
#Merge the two datasets
#  taking care that bins are all 1-wide, but some bins
#  may be missing from one of the two datasets
df <- merge(mod, obs, by="x", all=TRUE)
# I set all NAs to 0, since this means the bin is empty in the PDF
df[is.na(df)] <- 0

# Perform AD test
library(kSamples)
ad <- ad.test(df$PDF.x, df$PDF.y)
```

This gives me something like this:

```
> ad

 Anderson-Darling k-sample test.

Number of samples:  2
Sample sizes:  131, 131
Number of ties: 104

Mean of  Anderson-Darling  Criterion: 1
Standard deviation of  Anderson-Darling  Criterion: 0.75587

T.AD = ( Anderson-Darling  Criterion - mean)/sigma

Null Hypothesis: All samples come from a common population.

              AD  T.AD  asympt. P-value
version 1: 50.59 65.61        3.297e-28
version 2: 51.40 66.69        1.418e-28
```

Thus I think I should use the T.AD value to compare different datasets. Is this correct? Is the AD the right tool for this? Should I use CDFs instead? Roght now I only have PDFs as input, unfortunately.

I am especially interested in the extremes of the distribution. Is it correct to fill with zeroes the values which are not present for one dataset? These are PDFs, so in theory it should be OK.

Comment: Just to clarify you want to use the AD-statistic to check what? You say you want to check  the *goodness of fit test for some PDF distributions* but then proceed to get it two samples come from a common population. Can you please provide more information about what you want to achieve?

Comment: Sure. I have a set of models, of which I have the PDF. Then a set or observations, of which I also have the PDF. I want to compare the models and see which one of them is nearer to the observations. I can do this (and already do) with many metrics, but I'd like to add the AD to the list since it takes into account also the extremes of the distribution (a thing the KL and KS metrics do not show).

Comment: @usεr11852 sorry to bother, have you any ideas on the answer to the question above? I've had no input whatsoever... :(